# parseInt("010", 10); vs. parseInt(010, 10);

Tags: javascript

I'm confused about a particular result of `parseInt`. I thought I understood most of its quirks, but this one is unclear.

```
parseInt("010", 10); // 10

parseInt(010, 10);   // 8, but expecting 10
```

In the second example I specified the correct radix. What's the reason for the unexpected result?

**Solution**

The problem is with octal literal. When a number is prepended with 0, it's seen an as octal literal.

If you execute

```
console(010); // 8
```

in non-script mode, you will get 8. The reason that parseInt is having what I thought was strange behavior was because I was essentially executing

```
parseInt(8, 10); // 8
```

and expecting 10.

ParseInt never saw 010, only 8. Thanks to everyone for helping out.

Comment: Why would you want to use parseInt on a Number literal anyway?

Comment: It't not a practical use, but I couldn't stop wondering.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The number is being parsed before being passed to `parseInt`.

For example, it's similar to how this works:

```
var x = 010;
console.log(x); // 8
parseInt(x, 10);
```

Since you're passing 8 in, of course you're going to get 8 back. Prepending a number with 0 will make it an octal literal, which is using a base of 8. You can either remove the leading 0 (having the leading 0 there doesn't really make sense in the first place), or (as you did in your question) pass it as a string.

Note that not all browsers do this, it is simply ones that are compatible with previous code that do this (it's not required), and [implementations **must not** parse octal literals in ES5 strict mode](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-B.1.1). To see this in effect, compare the non-strict version:

```
(function ()
{   // not strict
    parseInt(010, 10);
})();
```

... which returns either 8 or 10 (depending on the implementation), with the strict version:

```
(function ()
{   "use strict";
    parseInt(010, 10);
})();
```

This will result in a `SyntaxError: Octal literals are not allowed in strict mode.`.

Answer (score 10):

Number literals beginning with zero are in [octal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal), rather than [decimal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal), so `010` is equal to `8`, unless operating under [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/Strict_mode).

It's important to note that the behavior of `parseInt` varies depending on what version of ECMAScript (JavaScript) your browser uses or if you're operating strict mode. See [Octal Interpretations with No Radix](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#Octal_Interpretations_with_No_Radix) for more detail.